# how to open whatsapp chat from andorid app from scanned QRCode without using mobile number?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, decode, qr-code

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.putExtra("jid", "91123456798" + "@s.whatsapp.net");
            sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

above code opens whatsappchat with given number

```
mCodeScanner.setDecodeCallback(new DecodeCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onDecoded(@NonNull Result result) {
              log.w("whatsappString" ,+result);
}
```

after scanning whtsapp QRcode with scanner it gives result like "https://wa.me/qr/VDHOMK2DXDDD1"

how to open perticular person chat using above link ? as i can not get mobile number after scanning code
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** get the phone number from the QR since the value after `../qr/` is decoded by WhatsApp. 
If you only want to open the WhatsApp application (that will later ask you to add the contact), once you have the qr code link `https://wa.me/qr/YOUR_CODE` you can just open the url using a normal intent. The code below should do the work and you will see a dialog prompting to chose between a browser or **Whatsapp if it is installed**:

```
val url = "https://wa.me/qr/YOUR_CODE"
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
startActivity(intent)
```